# Invalid server instance exception has occurred: There is no installed nodes! Please install node via NPM or download and install Appium

Tags: c#, appium

I'm using `Appium + C#` for mobile Automation and below is my pseudo-code:

```
AppiumLocalService _appiumLocalService = new AppiumServiceBuilder().UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
_appiumLocalService.Start();

var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["deviceName"]);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["platformVersion"]);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NoReset, true);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app"]);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appPackage"]);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appActivity"]);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("newCommandTimeout", 5000);
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("autoLaunch", false);
_driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(appiumOptions);
```

I'm getting the following error message:

`{"Invalid server instance exception has occurred: There is no installed nodes! Please install  node via NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html)"}`

Below you can see which settings I have already installed
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Appium with `npm install -g appium`. 
Then try again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help,but i already having the Appium with version of 1.18.0..